# Delphi to Windows fax

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

Anyone knows how can I send a fax with Windows 8 Fax true Delphi..I mean I need to launch the Windows Fax with number and pdf attachment.
Any tutorial about that ?
thnx.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Fax Service COM Interfaces`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684567%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for instance. For a simple manipulation, you can import the type library of the `fxscomex.dll` library and use a code like this (based on [`this example`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693482%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)):

```
uses
  ComObj, ActiveX, FAXCOMEXLib_TLB;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  JobIDs: OleVariant;
  FaxServer: IFaxServer2;
  FaxDocument: IFaxDocument2;
begin
  try
    FaxServer := CoFaxServer.Create;
    FaxServer.Connect('');
    FaxDocument := CoFaxDocument.Create;
    FaxDocument.Body := 'd:\Document.pdf';
    FaxDocument.DocumentName := 'Document name';
    FaxDocument.Recipients.Add('+1 (425) 555-4567', 'Bill');
    FaxDocument.Sender.Name := 'Bob';
    FaxDocument.Sender.BillingCode := '23A54';
    FaxDocument.Sender.Department := 'Accts Payable';
    FaxDocument.Sender.FaxNumber := '+972 (4) 555-9070';
    JobIDs := FaxDocument.ConnectedSubmit(FaxServer);

    for I := VarArrayLowBound(JobIDs, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(JobIDs, 1) do
      ShowMessage('Job ID: ' + VarArrayGet(JobIDs, [I]));
  except
    on E: EOleSysError do
      ShowMessage(
        Format('Sending of the fax failed! %s [%d]', [E.Message, E.ErrorCode])
      );
  end;
end;
```

Or the same without the type library:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
  JobIDs: OleVariant;
  FaxServer: OleVariant;
  FaxDocument: OleVariant;
begin
  try
    FaxServer := CreateOleObject('FaxComEx.FaxServer');
    FaxServer.Connect('');
    FaxDocument := CreateOleObject('FaxComEx.FaxDocument');
    FaxDocument.Body := 'd:\Document.pdf';
    FaxDocument.DocumentName := 'Document name';
    FaxDocument.Recipients.Add('+1 (425) 555-4567', 'Bill');
    FaxDocument.Sender.Name := 'Bob';
    FaxDocument.Sender.BillingCode := '23A54';
    FaxDocument.Sender.Department := 'Accts Payable';
    FaxDocument.Sender.FaxNumber := '+972 (4) 555-9070';
    JobIDs := FaxDocument.ConnectedSubmit(FaxServer);

    for I := VarArrayLowBound(JobIDs, 1) to VarArrayHighBound(JobIDs, 1) do
      ShowMessage('Job ID: ' + VarArrayGet(JobIDs, [I]));
  except
    on E: EOleSysError do
      ShowMessage(
        Format('Sending of the fax failed! %s [%d]', [E.Message, E.ErrorCode])
      );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Just one more question..Im getting a fax modem to test out the script how can I check if modem is present ?

Comment: That might be a good topic for a new question, but well, you can use [something like this](http://pastebin.com/6zUEFAbG) to determine the overall count of available fax devices on local machine (not their state though).